# add_menu_page() with variable function

Tags: functions, variables, add-menu-page

How can I use `add_menu_page()` functions some variable function ?

```
add_menu_page('My page','My page','manage_options','my_page', 'func' );

$func = function() {
        echo "Done !";
};
```

I know I can use like

```
function func() {
            echo "Done !";
};
```

But how can I use like

```
$func = function() {
            echo "Done !";
};
```

to call it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the closure before you call `add_menu_page()`:

```
$func = function() {
            echo "Done !";
};

add_menu_page('My page','My page','manage_options','my_page', $func );
```

Note you [need PHP 5.3](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) to do that.